# C# AWS GetParametersByPathRequest (how to write code flexible, intelligent & sophisticated enough to handle paths regardless of the hierarchy level?)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

The following packages are installed in my Visual Studio solution’s project:

```
Amazon.Extensions.Configuration.SystemsManager" Version="4.0.0" 
Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents" Version="2.5.0" 
Amazon.Lambda.Core" Version="2.1.0" 
Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson" Version="2.3.0" 
AWSSDK.S3" Version="3.7.9.21" 
AWSSDK.SecretsManager" Version="3.7.2.65" 
AWSSDK.SecretsManager.Caching" Version="1.0.4" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="3.1.27" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions" Version="3.1.27" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="3.1.27" 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.27" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.27" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.27" 
starkbank-ecdsa" Version="1.3.3" 
Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.3.0"
```

Let’s say that my AWS Cloud account has the following parameters:

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter1

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter2

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter3

> …..
> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Exodus/Chapter1

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Exodus/Chapter2

> …..
> /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/Mark/Chapter1

> /bible/NEwTestament/Gospel/Mark/Chapter2

> …..
> /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/John/Chapter1

> /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/John/Chapter2

```
    private GetParametersByPathResponse GetMyAppAWSParameters(string path)
    {
        GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest()
        {
            
            Path = path,
            WithDecryption = false
        };
        return _ssm.GetParametersByPathAsync(request).Result;
    }
```

The aforementioned method works with Paths that are just one-level up from the Leaf Node (i.e.,

> path = /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/

The returned response parameter list contains:

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter1

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter2

> /bible/OldTestament/Law/Genesis/Chapter3

Or

> path = /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/John/

The return response parameter list contains:

> /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/John/Chapter1

> /bible/NewTestament/Gospel/John/Chapter2

However, if I provide a shorter paths further up the hierarchy like the following:

path = /bible/OldTestament/Law/

Or

path = /bible/NewTestament/

Unfortunately The return response parameter list is empty

Essentially, I was trying to implement code that is flexible, intelligent & sophisticated enough to handle paths regardless of the hierarchy level. What code do I need to allow me to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works when I set Recursive to true.

```
 private GetParametersByPathResponse GetMyAppAWSParameters(string
path)
{
    GetParametersByPathRequest request = new GetParametersByPathRequest()
    {
        
        Path = path,
        Recursive = true,
        WithDecryption = false
    };
    return _ssm.GetParametersByPathAsync(request).Result;
}
```